# DataTables on click search per column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to active the seach per column on click of the related  element.

I managed to get the search box on click but it doesn't perform the search

I'm not that expert with javascript and jQuery but this is my code:

```
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#DataTable tfoot th').each(function () {

        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).click(function (event) {
            $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
            $(this).unbind('click');
        });

    });

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#DataTable').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            // Apply the search
            this.api().columns().every(function () {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change clear', function () {
                    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                        that
                            .search(this.value)
                            .draw();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Is there also a way to make the code shorter?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input doesn't exist at the point where you attach your `keyup change clear` event handler to it. You'll need to use delegated events instead.

```
initComplete: function() {
    this.api().columns().every(function() {
        var that = this;
        $(this.footer()).on('keyup change clear', 'input', function() {
            if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                that.search(this.value).draw();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

You can use [jQuery's `one` method](https://api.jquery.com/one/) to attach an event handler which will only be called once. You should also avoid creating multiple jQuery wrappers for the same input where you can.

```
$('#DataTable tfoot th').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.one("click", function (event) {
        $this.empty().append($('<input/>').attr("type", "search").attr("placeholder", "Search " + $this.text()));
    });
});
```